# не работает кнопка для обновления страници

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

нажимаю на кнопку но не обновляет страницу и при обновлении должно вывести баланс или слово Yes но не выводит не баланс не слово Yes 
в чем проблема? или напишите как должно бить 
буду блогодарен

```
<?php
require "db.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if( isset($_SESSION['logged_user']) ) : ?>
<p>Авторизован<br>Привет, 
<?php
 $data = $_POST;
 echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->login.'<br>';
 echo $_SESSION['logged_user']->balans.'<br>';
  if(isset($data['indexx']))
 {
  $users = R::load('users','7');
  $users->balans = '231';
  R::store($users);
  echo "yes";
 }
 echo $users->balans;

?>!
<from action="index.php" method="POST">
</p>
<hr>
<p>
 <button type="submit" name="indexx">+++++</button>
</p>
<a href="/logout.php">Выйти</a>
</from>
</body> 
</html>

<?php else : ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    ?>
 <a href="/login.php">Авторизоваться</a><br>
 <a href="/signup.php">Регистрация</a>
 </body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте опечатку исправить в теге "Form". У вас написано `<from>`, а надо `<form>`